# Mac OS X-like built-in dictionary in Ubuntu

Tags: macosx, dictionary, context-menu

Mac OS X has had for ages a feature that's been keeping me from trying or moving to other platforms: its built in Dictionary.app with American & British dictionaries as well as thesauri, plus dictionaries of various other languages. The fact that it's possible to triple-tap (or double-tap + "Look Up ") on a phrase of text/word in virtually all applications to have a dictionary pane pop-up, or search for a word in Spotlight and press enter for a full explanation of that word, is a major advantage.

Now, all this OS X praise aside: is it possible to achieve something equivalent/comparable in Ubuntu or any of its flavors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/). It's one of my favorite pieces of software. Cross-platform compatible dictionary look-up! It's highly customizable and compatible with a plethora of different dictionary formats and pretty much any website out there (e.g. wikipedia, dict.cc, etc.):

[image]

You can either install it from the [USC](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/goldendict) or get one of the latest development releases from [the OpenSUSE build repository](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:Tvangeste/goldendict) (e.g. for [12.04 LTS/amd64](https://build.opensuse.org/package/binary/home:Tvangeste/goldendict?arch=x86_64&filename=goldendict_1.5.git.1377084131_amd64.deb&repository=xUbuntu_12.04)).

As far as dictionaries are concerned, I'd suggest you install [Wordnet 3.0](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/goldendict-wordnet) to get started. Some notes on supported dictionary formats and where to find them may be found [here](http://goldendict.org/dictionaries.php).

Answer (score 4):

Artha dictionary also doing same job which I realized now.

It sets <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> as the shortcut initially which you can change.

And once you select a word and press those keys, the notification like thing pops up.