# Offline Dictionary Extension to run in background

Tags: 14.04, extension, dictionary, background-process

I would like to have a dictionary for offline use and which will be running in background. And when I select a word anywhere like in pdf, or in document, and it should pop-up or when I select the word and right click, there should be an option to get meaning.

Similar to google chrome has dictionary.com extension...

Is this available somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X-like built-in dictionary in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359144/mac-os-x-like-built-in-dictionary-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Stardict used to do this, but hasn't been developed in years.

Maybe one of these will work, they mostly seem to require internet access, though.: http://alternativeto.net/software/stardict/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you "GoldenDict", just run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install goldendict
```

Then you have to download your dictionaries in [FreeMdict Cloud](https://cloud.freemdict.com/index.php/s/pgKcDcbSDTCzXCs), there are a lot!

Open GoldenDict, in preferences, you have to enable "Scan Popup" for when selecting a word *anywhere* you can access the app by pop-up.

Hope it can help you!