# MAC OSX like offline dictionary on Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10

Tags: software-recommendation, mac, macosx, dictionary, context-menu

I have seen this [Mac OS X-like built-in dictionary in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359144/mac-os-x-like-built-in-dictionary-in-ubuntu) question's answer but goldendict is no more compatible with 14.04. It's dependencies can't be resolved due to older version.

MAC OSx has a good dictionary interface which can do lot of things when we hover a word in any where either it's browser or pdf or any docs it searches it's dictionary data as well as if it's possible then online.

Does Ubuntu has such application or software ?

Error from command `sudo apt-get --fix-missing  install goldendict`
 or `sudo apt-get install goldendict`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 goldendict : Depends: libavcodec53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but it is not installable or
                       libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but it is not installable
              Depends: libavformat53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but it is not installable or
                       libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but it is not installable
              Depends: libavutil51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but it is not installable or
                       libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: try command   `sudo apt-get -f install`  and then run `sudo apt-get install goldendict`